# Highcharts, how to pass value from drop down list and match it in mongodb data, and retrieve data to draw pie chart

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, highcharts

This is the current pie chart that I have and the drop down list of which the user will select one of the following to display data for that year. My problem is that I do not know how to pass the value of the option, i.e 2017, to the database to lookup the user selected year in the records. I feel like it would be in the $match function of mongodb/js file

[image: pie chart]

here is the html, in pug/jade

```
title Alliance Dashboard
meta(charset='utf-8')
meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
script(src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js')
script(src='http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js')
script(src='/javascripts/datamaps.world.min.js')
script(src='/javascripts/jquery.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', 
src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js')
script(type='text/javascript', 
src='http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js')

script(type='text/javascript').
  $(window).load(function(){

    var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)}
    var pie = !{JSON.stringify(pie)}
    //console.log(json);
    makeLine(data);
    makePie(pie);
    getMap();
    //getWorld();
  }); // Closes window.load

  //would like if for the years in dropdown list, to be fetched from database, so as to be not hardcoded
      select 
        option(name='year', value='2017') 2017
        option(name='year', value='2016') 2016 
        option(name='year', value='2016') 2015 
        option(name='year', value='2016') 2014
```

here is the script.js where the pie function is done

```
function makePie(pie){

Highcharts.chart('char2', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Nominal GDP'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>${point.y:.1f}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true //country label
            },
            showInLegend: true,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'GDP',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: pie
    }]
});
}
```

Here is I think where the actual retrieval of data from mongodb is done and in the $match section, is there a way to have 'year: option.selected.value (e.g, 2017)' instead of the hardcoded match?

```
exports.get_detail = function(req, res, next) {
async.parallel({
two: function(callback){ //pie
        Country.aggregate([
            {           
                $match: {
                     /*$and: [
                        {name: { $in: ["USA", "China", "India", "France", "Japan"]}},
                        {year: 2017}
                     ]*/
                    //want year to match selected year user clicks on in dropdown list. year is of type number
                    year: 2015
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    "nominalGDP": -1 //in descending order
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: 1,
                'y' : '$nominalGDP' //since there are no axes, only y values 
                                    //and name should be displayed
                }
            }       
            ], callback);
    }
}, function(err, results){
    console.log(results.one);
    console.log(results.two);

    res.render('hello', { title: 'Test', data: results.one, pie: results.two 
});
});
}
```

I've looked and search through many posts and the best lead that I have is using the value of the options to pass it through, but I can't figure it out by how or what syntax. This is all new to me.

Comment: I don't know how you can get the value, but you can easily send a parameter to the query. Suppose you have somewhere a variable with the value  option.selected.value. You can within the query say year: your_year_variable

Comment: ok, I think i have a rough idea. So basically if I see the option selected, then I can query that parameter...to which I can do year: my variable? 

if somehow I was able to,
e.g, var selectYear = req.body.id

Then I can do....$match:{ year: selectYear }?

Comment: that's correct.